# Remove Select Button in GridView for 1 row C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a total row in my GridView.

This has come back from the `SQL database` along with the data columns. I have a Template Field for the first column that allows the user to select the row(Standard stuff). What I want to do is remove the select option from the totals row.

I have the  row available in my `Row_Bound` event so I can see it, in fact I change the background color for only that row. It's `removing the select functionality` ONLY for that row that is my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you can set visibility of your select button based on the value of any field in that row. For example, if your data source contains a column named SomeFieldName and that column equals "Totals" in the totals row:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" visible='<%#Eval("SomeFieldName") != "Totals" %>' />
```

Comment: Hi, your are right that would work but then my headers would be out for the Total row. I really want to keep the column structure but remove the 'select' functionality.

Comment: Just my c# 
               List<DashboardMonthTotalsByBusinessGroupLevelByYearMonth2Result> list = dal.GetDivisionalData(groupId, selectedYear, SessionManager.SelectedMonth);

Comment: then... CostCentreGridView.DataSource = list;
                CostCentreGridView.DataBind();